# How to translate "as though it were" in german?

Tags: english-to-german

I'm trying to translate following sentence in German. Would I use for "as though it were" to "als ob es ... wäre" or "als wäre es ..."?

> For example, patients might read "love" as though it were loave, and
>   "head" as heed. *(Beispielweise könnten Patienten "love" als wäre es "loave", und "head" als "heed" lesen.)*

Comment: Simple "als" would do the job too - "Patienten könnten "love" als "loave" lesen".

Answer (score 5):

I put in in a different context:

> Michael drinks wine as though it were water.

This is in German:

> a) Michael trinkt Wein wie Wasser.
>   b) Michael trinkt Wein als wäre es Wasser.
>   c) Michael trinkt Wein wie wenn es Wasser wäre.
>   d) Michael trinkt Wein als ob es Wasser wäre.

All four versions are possible, and all four mean the same: Michael knows the difference between Wine and Water, but he drinks wine in a manner like other people drink water. Which of this four versions you use depends on personal flavor.

But this is wrong:

> e) Michael trinkt Wein fälschlicherweise als Wasser.

This means: Michael wanted to drink Water, but by error he grabbed a bottle of wine, drinks it instead, and doesn't notice the difference.

Comment: Using your example your translation of "as though it were" fits best, but what is about Dragut's example?

Comment: Answer c) sounds truly unnatural. The other 3 are finde and equal.

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagy: I added c) because to me d) sounds a little bit unnatural, and c) was the more natural alternative. But I guess, this is because of different regional preferences (I'm living in the east of Austria).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Yess, well possible. Despite my name I live in southern Germany. Here we'd consider the usage of "wie" where "als" is possible as either youth slang or simply wrong: "Er ist größer wie ich". The c) is neither slang nor wrong, yet for me it feels that way.

Answer (score 2):

Both *als ob es ... wäre* and *als wäre es ...* sound wrong in your example.

I would translate it as

> Beispielweise könnten Patienten "love" **fälschlicherweise als** "loave" und "head" **(fälschlicherweise) als** "heed" lesen.

*Fälschlicherweise* is translated back to English as *falsely* or *by mistake*. So yes, there is a jugdement about what is the correct way to read it. Das "as though it were" in Dragut's example does not make this explicite judgement, but still indicated what is correct and what is not.

Comment: nice tipps by the way "q" and "w" must be side by side on your keyboard layout.It is the same on mine.

Comment: But »because of an error« and »as though it were« are not the same thing. So your answer is wrong.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast maybe Iris tried to convey saying "falschlicherweise" not to "because of an error" but "because of obstacle", yes there is no an error actually, it is just a language disorder.

Comment: The point is: »fälschlicherweise« makes a judgement. This word clearly says »this is wrong«. But »as though it were« dosn't judge. It doesn't say that it is wrong (it doesn't say its correct either). It's neutral on behalf of right or wrong. »As though it were« only says »in the manner of« or »like« without any judgement.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast, I concentrated on the example and there "als wäre es" soiunds wrong. Maybe the example in the OP is not well chosen.